# Onclick on option tags if onchange is not enough

Tags: javascript, select, dom-events, onchange

I have **two selects A and B** which trigger on onchange event the same ajax request which rewrites some content area. 
If I click on the **option A in select A** onchange works well and ajax call rewrites the content. 
Then if I click on the **option B in select B** this ajax call also rewrites the  content. 
And here is the problem. If I then want to select **option A in select A** which **remained selected** from the first action it does not triggers onchange event (cause is already selected).

How to solve it if click event is not supported on option tags? I tried to deselect option tag after onchange like

```
complete: function()
{
    $(this).prop("selected", false);
}
```

but this also does not triggers onchange event even if option is deselected. How to solve it? Thanks.

Example https://jsfiddle.net/h7cokr6b/1/

Comment: Hard to understand exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish. Definitely can not use events on `<option>` cross browser. Please provide more code context and a better explanation of expected behavior

Comment: The problem is the option A from the first step is selected and does not trigger onchange event. Also if I deselect it via ```$(this).prop("selected", false);```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Here is the example https://jsfiddle.net/h7cokr6b/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
complete: function()
{
    $(this).prop("selectedIndex", 0); // It has to be default selected value's index.
}
```

Comment: Hmm it seems this works https://jsfiddle.net/h7cokr6b/3/ But what is selectedIndex and what is support in browsers... Also thanks a lot.

Comment: But it is little user unfriendly if user cant see previous selected option. May be I'll change select to html ul list with anchors.

Answer (score 0):

use `.unbind('change').bind('change', function(){ /// do something });` jQuery event before binding new event or use `$('#optionA, #optionB').off().on('change', function(){ /// do something });` to detach events before attaching new one.

Comment: what does this have to do with `<select>` element?

Comment: $('#optionA, #optionB').off().on('change', function(){
   /// do something
});

It won't attach new event if one is already attached.

Comment: `off()` also requires event name argument as minimum

Comment: if you do not provide any arguments in `off()`, it removes all event handlers attached with that element.

Comment: This also does not work. ```$(this).closest('select').off().on('change', getJob);``` cause option A is still selected.

Comment: use `$("select#A").prop('selectedIndex',0);`

Comment: Hey man it looks selectedIndex works look https://jsfiddle.net/h7cokr6b/3/ But it looks weird. What is it selectedIndex and whant is the support in browsers?

Comment: you should try onClick event instead. because onChange event fires only when you change something in select option.

Comment: I tried onclick but the problem is that if you want to  show option list you must click on select which will always trigger the callback.

Comment: you can not use events on `<option>` , they are not supported cross browser

Comment: inside click event see if the desired option is selected, `if($(this).prop('selectedIndex') == 1) { //process }`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is to set a new value on one select and to *"trigger change event"*

Assume you have the following

```
$('#select1, #select2').on('change', function(){
   /// do something
});
```

You can set a value on one of those elements and trigger a change after you set the new value

```
$('#select1').val('newValue').change() // or .trigger('change')
```

Comment: But this is hard coded. How can I trigger change() if I can't catch it? How can I detect that I should trigger change() manually?

Comment: This goes back to needing you to provide a [mcve] so we aren't guessing

Comment: Ok I'll try to make some jsfiddle example.

Comment: What should happen? A `<select>` doesn't have a `selected` property. Still not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: I think I know what you want...to be able to **deselect** an option is that it? Only way to do that is with a button or something. no event will fire when you click on a selected option unless it is a `<select multiple>`. Or have an option that says "None" and value is empty

Comment: Look at this example from comments below https://jsfiddle.net/h7cokr6b/3/ What do you thing about it?

Comment: I think it isn't user friendly. A user selects something they shouldn't see it revert to original  **Still not clear what objective is or what higher level problem you are trying to solve**

Comment: Yes it is little user unfriendly. May be I'll change select to html ul/ol list with anchors....